# WIX Burn: MSI in Chain is Not Installed

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I have a WIX Burn Bootstapper and I have a problem. On some computers it will install both the MSI files in the chain. However most of the time it will skip the first item in the Chain like it's not even there, any ideas? Specifically it wont install the IntelSDK.

```
<Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id="IntelSDK"  Name="IntelSDK" Visible="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" SourceFile="PATH-TO-MSI-ON-MY-MACHINE" />
  <MsiPackage Id="CameraApp"  Name="CameraApp" Visible="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" SourceFile="PATH-TO-MSI-ON-MY-MACHINE" />
</Chain>
```

Log Files(There was 2):

[Log File](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TmkpQOk-zNFsxEMVFKUoK5SBoIHFzwksxDdQWcmLZS8/edit?usp=sharing)

[Long Log File(Verbose)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xau3ILudrFT_CCmS3xSYcDIgm5k2xMPaoP7duU_R3U0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Post the bootstrapper log (logs to %temp%) it will have information for the Plan portion of the install which should show you why it is deciding to not install IntelSDK.

Comment: Posted (See Above, they are google docs links, only way I could get the formatting to look ok)

Comment: I get access denied when trying to access Log File.

Comment: Sorry about that, all fixed

Answer (score 4):

It thinks that it's already installed:

```
i101: Detected package: IntelSDK, state: Present, cached: Complete
```

It won't install a package if it's detected as `Present`.

Comment: So it says that, but the MSI does not show up in my Programs and Features?

Comment: @TylerTallo Burn uses Windows API's to detect whether MSI's are installed, so Windows thinks it's installed.  Maybe you didn't always have the `Visible` attribute set to `yes`?